# Use ToString() for lambda in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, lambda

The field DateOfBirth has the type `DateTime`.
I want to apply method `ToString()` in View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DateOfBirth).ToString("D")
```

But it doesn't work, because method `ToString` has 0 parameters.

I resolved this problem.
In model I have the second field:

```
    public string DateOfBirth2
    {
        get { return DateOfBirth.ToString("D"); }
    }
```

And then I use this field in View.

But I want to know, if I can use method `ToString("D")` in View.

Comment: Add the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:D}")]` to your property, and then its just `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateOfBirth)`

Answer (score 1):

You should display the property directly, without using `DisplayFor`:

```
@Model.DateOfBirth.ToString("D");
```